# How can I style my form (selectable dropdown box) when it is disabled? (react bootstrap)

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, react-bootstrap

My site looks like:

country_______ -> state________ -> city_________

Where dropdown boxes are at each selection.

When a `country` other than `USA` is selected, I disable the `state` selection and it shows, but it's grayed out and nothing can be selected.

I want the state selection box to disappear altogether or at least just become a gray box with no text.

```
<ControlLabel>State</ControlLabel>

<FormControl
    componentClass="select"
    value={this.state.state} 
    name="state"
    onChange={this.handleChange}
>
    { data["state"].map((d) => <option key={d} value={d} disabled={this.state.disabled_state}>{d}</option>) }
</FormControl>

if(name === "country" && (value === "China" || value === "Brazil")) {
    this.setState({ disabled_state : true});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[JSX](https://reactjs.org/docs/introducing-jsx.html) allows you to do that directly. Just assign to a variable the `JSX` code that you want depending on `disabled_state`, and render that variable later on. If you don't want to render anything, just assign `null` or an empty string to the variable:

Declare a different `JSX` code depending on `disabled_state`:

```
const stateFormControl = this.state.disabled_state
    ? (
          <div>disable_state is true</div>
      )
    : (
          <FormControl
              componentClass="select"
              value={this.state.state} 
              name="state"
              onChange={this.handleChange}
          >
              { data["state"].map((d) => <option key={d} value={d} disabled={this.state.disabled_state}>{d}</option>) }
          </FormControl>
      );
```

And in the return of the component, render that variable:

```
<ControlLabel>State</ControlLabel>
{ stateFormControl  }
```

Here you have a working snippet. If you select a country other than `USA` an `Alert` element is rendered instead of the `FormControl` element:

```js
const { Form, Alert } = ReactBootstrap;
const FormControl = Form.Control;

const FormExample = () => {
  
  const [state, setState] = React.useState(true);
  const countriesOptions = ["USA", "CHINA", "KOREA"];
  const statesOptions = ["Alabama", "Alaska", "Arizona"];
  
  const countrySelected = (evt) => setState(evt.target.value === "USA");
  
  const stateElement = state
    ? (
          <FormControl as="select">
              { statesOptions.map(s => <option key={s}>{s}</option>) }    
          </FormControl>
      )
    : (
          <Alert variant="danger">No state for this country</Alert>
      );
  
  return (
    <Form>
      <FormControl as="select" onChange={countrySelected}>
        { countriesOptions.map(c => <option key={c}>{c}</option>) }
      </FormControl>
      { stateElement }
    </Form>
  );
  
};

ReactDOM.render(
  <FormExample />,
  document.getElementById('example')
);
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.6/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.6/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-bootstrap@next/dist/react-bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div id="example"></div>
```